# Produce solutions such that $k$&$x$ $=$ $k$,in a range ($0$,$n$)

Tags: binary, binary-operations

How to efficiently generate all numbers within $0,1,2...n$.
(very large $n$).
Such that for a fixed $x$ and $k$ ($0<=k<=n$), $k$&$x$=$k$.
It is easily found out that all the bits with value $1$ in $k$ is also $1$ in $x$.
But I have trouble computing all of them.
Do I have to consider each and every bit which needs to be changed to get all the possibilities?Any other efficient way? Also I certainly dont want to check with all of $n$.

Comment: is $\&$ a bitwise addition ?

Comment: @JeanMarie it is more of multiplication. 0 & 1 = 0 , 1 & 1 = 1 ,0 & 0=0.It is a bitwise and.

Comment: It was what I meant (I thought to boolean addition), but it's better to say "bitwise and" as you do.

Comment: Say you have $N$ bits, and for $k$ you have $K$ bits that are equal to 1. Then you need to generate $2^{N-K}$ numbers. As for how to do it efficiently, that depends on the programming language